# Draw in a second Java Applet Window

Tags: java, applet, window, frame, draw

i am trying for days to add a second window to my applet in which i want to draw mathematical graphs. Getting the second window is no problem, but i can't get the drawing to work. Maybe you can help me. This is my latest try:

```
import java.awt.*;


public class FFrame extends Frame{

    public FFrame(){

        Panel p = new MyPanel();
        add(p);
    }

    private class MyPanel extends Panel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponents(g);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 100);        
        }
    };
}
```

I add this to my applet by creating a new FFrame-Object "f" and run `f.show()` in the `init()` method. I don't use swing, by the way.

Comment: Typo here ? `super.paintComponents(g);` has to be `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: eclipse marks paintComponent(s) as undefined for type Panel.

Comment: it `paintComponent(g)` and not `paintComponent(s)`

Comment: of course. made just a mistake in my comment here